# R: Aggregate column of values to multiple new columns, each based on index column

Tags: r, recursion, merge, aggregate

Assume I have data:

```
data.frame(Plot = rep(1:2,3),Index = rep(1:3, each = 2), Val = c(1:6)*10)

  Plot Index Val
1    1     1  10
2    2     1  20
3    1     2  30
4    2     2  40
5    1     3  50
6    2     3  60
```

I want to create new columns combining/aggregating all `Val` that share a common `Index` for a given `Plot`. I want to do this for each `Index`.

```
  Plot Val1 Val2 Val3
1    1   10   30   50
2    2   20   40   60
```

I would like any remaining columns (e.g., just `Plot` in this simplified example) to remain in my final data.frame.

**My Attempt**

I know I can do this step-wise using `aggregate()` and `merge()`, but is there a way to do this using a single (or minimal) call(s)?

- Any approach is great, but I always like to see an elegant base R approach if one exists...

### Update:

I'm looking for a solution that also works well when other columns are involved:

```
dat2 = data.frame(Plot = rep(1:2,each = 8),Year = rep(rep(2010:2011, each = 4),2), 
                  Index = rep(rep(1:2,2),4), Val = rep(c(1:4)*10,4))

   Plot Year Index Val
1     1 2010     1  10
2     1 2010     2  20
3     1 2010     1  30
4     1 2010     2  40
5     1 2011     1  10
6     1 2011     2  20
7     1 2011     1  30
8     1 2011     2  40
9     2 2010     1  10
10    2 2010     2  20
11    2 2010     1  30
12    2 2010     2  40
13    2 2011     1  10
14    2 2011     2  20
15    2 2011     1  30
16    2 2011     2  40

#Resulting in (if aggregating by sum, for example):

  Plot Year Val1 Val2 
1    1 2010   40   60 
2    1 2011   40   60 
3    2 2010   40   60 
4    2 2011   40   60
```

Also, ideally, the new columns could be named based on the `Index` value.

- So if my index were instead A:C, my new columns would be `ValA`, `ValB`, and `ValC`

Comment: `as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(Val~Plot+Index,dat))`

Comment: `do.call(data.frame,aggregate(Val~Plot,dat,I))`

Comment: `reshape2::dcast(dat,Plot~Index)`

Comment: `tidyr::spread(dat,Index,Val)`

Comment: Thanks @Onyambu. your `as.data.frame.matrix` works as expected (without including the `Plot` column, which is fine cause I can add it back easily enough). However, you `do.call` approach does not work as expected with an expanded example data set (e.g., with additional indexing columns)

Comment: Also, it would be ideal for the column names to have names that match the index.

Comment: what do you mean by **additional indexing columns**? The `do.call` transforms the result into a `data.frame`.

Comment: @Onyambu for example, a data.frame containing both `Plot` and `Year`: `dat2 = data.frame(Plot = rep(1:2,6),Year = rep(rep(2010:2012, each = 2),2), Index = rep(rep(1:3, each = 2),2), Val = rep(c(1:6)*10,2))`

Comment: I get what you mean.. `aggregate` is not meant to reshape the data. there is a `reshape` function. Although it depends on where you want to put the `year` should it be a grouping factor? If not then you can still use `aggregate` as `do.call(data.frame,aggregate(cbind(Val,year)~Plot,dat,I))`..But I do not thing this is what you need. Try using the `spread` from `tidyr::` or even `dcast|acast` from `reshape2::`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want a base R solution: then you can do something like:

```
m = aggregate(Val~.,dat2,sum)
reshape(m,v.names = "Val",idvar = c("Plot","Year"),timevar = "Index",direction = "wide")
  Plot Year Val.1 Val.2
1    1 2010    40    60
2    2 2010    40    60
3    1 2011    40    60
4    2 2011    40    60
```

But you can use other  functions:

```
do.call(data.frame,aggregate(Val~Plot+Year,m,I))
  Plot Year Val.1 Val.2
1    1 2010    40    60
2    2 2010    40    60
3    1 2011    40    60
4    2 2011    40    60
```

Or using the `reshape2` library, you can tackle the problem as:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(dat2,Plot+Year~Index,sum,value.var = "Val")
  Plot Year  1  2
1    1 2010 40 60
2    1 2011 40 60
3    2 2010 40 60
4    2 2011 40 60
```

Comment: Why do you need base R?

Comment: `aggregate(Val~Plot+Year,aggregate(Val~.,dat2,sum),I)`

Answer (score 1):

One can think of using `gather`, `unite` and `spread` functions to get the desired result as mentioned by OP.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(Plot = rep(1:2,3),Index = rep(1:3, each = 2), Val = c(1:6)*10)


df %>% gather(key, value, -Plot, -Index) %>%
  unite("key", c(key,Index), sep="") %>%
  spread(key, value)

#   Plot Val1 Val2 Val3
# 1    1   10   30   50
# 2    2   20   40   60
```

**Note:** There are other short options (as correctly pointed out by @Onyambu) but then again per OP's desire column's names required to be changed.

```
spread(df, Index, Val)
#   Plot  1  2  3
# 1    1 10 30 50
# 2    2 20 40 60

aggregate(Val~Plot,df,I)
#   Plot Val.1 Val.2 Val.3
# 1    1    10    30    50
# 2    2    20    40    60
```

**Updated:** Based on 2nd data frame from OP.

```
dat2 = data.frame(Plot = rep(1:2,each = 8),Year = rep(rep(2010:2011, each = 4),2), 
                  Index = rep(rep(1:2,2),4), Val = rep(c(1:4)*10,4))


library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

dat2 %>% gather(key, value, -Plot, -Index, -Year) %>%
  unite("key", c(key,Index), sep="") %>%
  dcast(Plot+Year~key, value.var = "value")

#   Plot Year Val1 Val2
# 1    1 2010    2    2
# 2    1 2011    2    2
# 3    2 2010    2    2
# 4    2 2011    2    2
```